# Varios proyectos GIT con cosas en común y cosas diferentes

Tags: php, git, ingenieria-del-software, administración-de-software

Tengo una e-commerce desarrollado desde cero. Para cada cliente tengo que personalizar ciertas partes. ¿Cómo sería la mejor estrategia para mantener el código de todos clientes?

A) ¿Un único proyecto GIT con una rama por cliente? De esta manera la incorporación de correcciones de bugs es bastante inmediata. El problema es que cada instanciación de cada cliente la tengo en servidores diferentes. ¿Varios remotos? Un poco lío.

B) ¿Varios proyectos GIT, uno por cada cliente? Cada proyecto sería independiente, puedo tenerlo cada uno en su servidor y no habría lío con los remotos, cada uno el suyo.

C) ¿Subtrees de GIT (no tengo ni idea de cómo va esto)?

D) ¿Módulos de GIT (no tengo ni idea de cómo va esto)?

Comment: Yo optaria por la primera opción, y además agregaría una tarea deploy donde esta "deployee" en el servidor correspondiente a cada cliente.

Comment: para manejo de submódulos ver https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Herramientas-de-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos

Comment: siendo php también podes empaquetar con composer para manejar mejor las versiones y dependencias https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#satis

Comment: Hola, también iría por la primera opción, un único proyectos con varias ramas, es la alternativa que mas se esta manejando actualmente creo. Las ramas con nombres descriptivos, como producción, testing, etc.